# closing jquery modal dialog is slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a modal dialog where I place the contents of an html form inside. The form has a submit and cancel button. I'm finding the cancel button or even closing the dialog by hitting the x quite slow. It is only a few seconds too slow but it is long enough to think there is a problem that crazy mouse clickers might go nuts.

Is there a better way to use the close function and a better way to cancel the changes than what I'm doing:

```
var $dialog = $('#cameraform').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625,
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close'); //this is slow
    }
}); //init dialog

//events            
$('.addwebcam').click(function(e) {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});

$(".cancel_changes").click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('close');    //this is slow
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="addwebcam">Add Webcam</button>
<div id="cameraform" title="Add a camera">
...//my form
<button type='button' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Any optimization I can do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not leaving firebug open during this are you? I'm assuming you're using jQueryUI, and if that's the case, dialog should not be that slow. Do you have a bunch of other script running on the page?

Comment: No, but holy cow I just found out why you asked. With Firebug open it is even more brutal, I even crashed my browser.

Comment: Yeah, best to do your debugging with firebug and then turn it off when you don't need it. It makes js heavy pages run slooooow.

Comment: @jm2 FWIW I've never experienced any significant slow downs when using the Chrome debugger.

Comment: @Alnitak I am highly addicted to my battery of FF addons, otherwise I might make the switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the close call from the close event on your dialog setup:

```
var $dialog = $('#cameraform').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625,
    close: function() {
      //  $(this).dialog('close'); //this is slow
    }
}); //init dialog
```

You are calling the close event from within itself, thus resulting in a overflow of the call stack.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I thought this was necessary to be able to close the window.

Comment: @Tom no, that hook is to allow you to do other stuff automatically as the dialog is closing.

Comment: Missed that at first glance. Nice eye!