# JQuery UI dialog slow process when close after a function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this similar [closing jquery modal dialog is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163082/closing-jquery-modal-dialog-is-slow) question, but in this example, it does not use `buttons` attribute which is my issue. How can I close the dialog without using $( this ).dialog( "close" ) after a function is called?

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/as9k8nxf/) for demo

```
 var begin = new Date();
  $(function() { 
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
         // $( this ).dialog( "close" ); too slow
            foo();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );  too slow
            foo();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

- u can trigger close just after putting your close code post callling foo(); or better can use callback functions.

see below code , hope it helps.

```js
 var begin = new Date();
 $(function() {

   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
     resizable: false,
     height: 140,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
       "Delete all items": function() {
         // $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         foo();
       },
       Cancel: function() {
         foo(clsPopUp);


       }
     }
   });
 });

 function clsPopUp() {
   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
 }

 function foo(callback) {
   var end = new Date();
   alert((end - begin) / 1000);
   callback();
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<body>

  <div id="dialog-confirm">
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).parent().hide();
```

Instead of:

```
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
```